# pl/sql save hierarchical query to variable

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am trying to save result set of hierarchical query to variable

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test12 
    RETURN number IS
      result number(4):=0; 
      clli_array dbms_sql.varchar2_table;
    BEGIN 
       with tmp as (select 'strforregexp' str from dual) 
       select regexp_substr(str, '\/([A-Z0-9]{11}|[A-Z0-9]{8})', 1, level) STR into :clli_array from tmp
       connect by regexp_substr(str, '\/([A-Z0-9]{11}|[A-Z0-9]{8})', 1, level) is not null;
    END test12;
```

But getting an error

> Error(9,9): PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'CLLI_ARRAY'

So, i have 2 questions

1) can i get all matches of regexp witohout hierarchical query

2) why i am getting an error

Comment: We don't use a colon when referencing local variables. Just `into clli_array `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @APC pointed out, the first problem is that you've got a colon in front of `CLLI_ARRAY`. This causes the PL/SQL compiler to believe that `CLLI_ARRAY` is going to be a SQL*Plus substitution variable, and when it finds that such a variable is not defined it throws the error you got.

However, even if you remove the colon you're not out of the woods yet. Once you remove the colon you'll get

```
PLS-00597: expression 'CLLI_ARRAY' in the INTO list is of wrong type
```

That's because `CLLI_ARRAY` is a PL/SQL-type collection, but your statement returns a single string.

What you probably want to do is to use BULK COLLECT to have the system retrieve all the results of the query into your VARCHAR2_TABLE:

```
with tmp as (select 'strforregexp' str from dual)
select regexp_substr(str, '\/([A-Z0-9]{11}|[A-Z0-9]{8})', 1, level) STR
  BULK COLLECT into clli_array
  from tmp
  connect by regexp_substr(str, '\/([A-Z0-9]{11}|[A-Z0-9]{8})', 1, level) is not null
```

Best of luck.